# Splitting a Pandas single column into multiple sum columns

Tags: pandas

Here's a Noob question.

Let's say I have this Pandas DataFrame of data:

```
   id     Name      Sex Age   Country         Sport         Medal
119932  K Thompson  M   26  United States   Basketball      Gold    
120121  V Thrasher  F   19  United States   Shooting        Gold    
122093  M Troy      M   27  United States   Volleyball      Bronze  
123943  J Valente   F   21  United States   Cycling         Silver  
125943  D Verburg   M   25  United States   Athletics       Gold    

71921   L Xiaojun   M   20  China           Weightlifting   Silver
69571   L Yuehong   M   26  China           Shooting        Bronze
69955   L Chaopan   M   20  China           Gymnastics      Bronze
69978   L Li        F   24  China           Volleyball      Gold

123361  L Unsworth  F   21  Great Britain   Hockey          Gold
128077  B Walkden   F   22  Great Britain   Taekwondo       Bronze
128145  C Walker    M   28  Great Britain   Swimming        Silver
128156  D Wallace   M   20  Great Britain   Swimming        Silver
```

Now I could do all of this by looping, using if statements, etc... but I want to know if there is a way by Grouping (using GroupBy) the data by country, and then I create three new columns that lists the number of medals won, like this:

```
                    Gold        Silver      Bronze
Country
Great Britian       1           2           1
China               1           1           2
United States       3           1           1
```

so then how can I (or is it possible) create a new columns using lambda and .apply() to the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to split the dataframe into groups based on "Country" and "Medal"
2. Then apply the [`.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) aggregate method to get the size of each group
3. Lastly use[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with the `fill_value` parameter to replace any NaNs with 0 and flatten the dataframe

```py
df.groupby(['Country', 'Medal']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: It's halfway getting the result that I wanted, however, the "Country" column isn't part of the index and it is missing. The df.columns gives this: Index(['Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'], dtype='object', name='Medal'). So if I wanted a specific total of medals won for "Great Britian", it's not possible.

Comment: The country is the index. You can access it as so: `df.loc['United States']` for example. However, if you swap the order of the groups, it should work as you expect. Try doing `df.groupby(['Medal', 'Country']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Country'], df['Medal'])
```

Output:

```
Medal          Bronze  Gold  Silver
Country                            
China               2     1       1
Great Britain       1     1       2
United States       1     3       1
```

If you want specific order of medal, chain that with a reindex:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['Country'], df['Medal'])
   .reindex(['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'], fill_value=0, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
Medal          Gold  Silver  Bronze
Country                            
China             1       1       2
Great Britain     1       2       1
United States     3       1       1
```